# Assign dictionary key and priority value wherever conditions from a dictionary are met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, select

I have a dictionary of conditions called `rules`, which I apply to a dataframe `df`. Using numpy's `select()`, I create a new column in `df` with the dictionary keys where ever the first condition is True. The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'col2': [4, 4, 4, 3]})
rules = {"Alert 1": df["col1"] == 1,
         "Alert 2": df["col2"] == 4}
df['alert'] = np.select(rules.values(), rules.keys(), default = None)

df
Out[2]: 
   col1  col2    alert
0     1     4  Alert 1
1     2     4  Alert 2
2     1     4  Alert 1
3     3     3     None
```

I would like to change the dictionary `rules` such that it consists of vectors that contain the original conditions plus a priority value. In addition to the dictionary key being written to `df`, I would like this priority to be written as well. Modification to `rules`, as well as my attempt to write both the dictionary key and priority to `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'col2': [4, 4, 4, 3]})
rules = {"Alert 1": [df["col1"] == 1, "High"],
         "Alert 2": [df["col2"] == 4, "Medium"]}
df['alert'] = np.select(rules.values()[0], rules.keys(), default = None)
df['priority'] = np.select(rules.values()[0], rules.values()[1], default = None)
```

I get an  error.

Ideally, I would like the output

```
   col1  col2    alert  priority
0     1     4  Alert 1      High
1     2     4  Alert 2    Medium
2     1     4  Alert 1      High
3     3     3     None      None
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

P.S. I need to keep the priority with the condition in the dictionary. I don't want a separate dictionary which maps the priority onto the dictionary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to stick with your current approach, you could use tuples to contain all of the values you need for each key.  In this case you just need to pull the values at index 0 for the `alert` and map the resulting values to index 1 for the `priority`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'col2': [4, 4, 4, 3]})
rules = {"Alert 1": ([df["col1"] == 1, "High"]),
         "Alert 2": ([df["col2"] == 4, "Medium"])}

    
df['alert']  = np.select([x[0] for x in rules.values()], rules.keys(), default = None)
df['priority'] = df['alert'].map({k:v[1] for k,v in rules.items()})
```

Output

```
   col1  col2    alert priority
0     1     4  Alert 1     High
1     2     4  Alert 2   Medium
2     1     4  Alert 1     High
3     3     3     None      NaN
```

Comment: Howzit Chris. You are the best.